# Software to draw graph from OSM map?

Tags: openstreetmap, graph, josm

I am new in OSM, I have downloaded the data of my map from OSM using the JOSM and i have saved it in a *.xml format.

I'm trying to **convert a nodes and a edges (ways) from a OSM map to a graph** ( connected graph for example) ...  ... can we do somthing like taht ?? Is there a **software** to do it ???

someone will say me, try to use the '**GraphView**' plugin, but, whaht i need is a specifique **software or another way** to draw a graph frome xml file for a OSM map ...

I googled a lot, but either I used the wrong keywords or there are no simple solutions on the internet.

Comment: A graph for what? Routing?

Comment: yes, for routing (y)

Comment: In what format and which kind of resolution?

Usually most people use [osm2pgrouting](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgrouting) , [Trafficmining](http://code.google.com/p/trafficmining/) or [eWorld](http://eworld.sourceforge.net/) as parsing OSM and understanding the right tagging schemas is a lot of work ...

Comment: my dear, i want to draw a graph with the nodes of the xml file of my map, and then i want to save it as picture ... have u an idea ???

Comment: Do you have an example of what you expect in result?

Comment: First you said [routing](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing), then you said [rendering](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering). Are you sure you know what you want?

Comment: Dear @scai, i need routing & rendering !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to understand your intention as routing graph is usually what people are talking about and even just a picture needs an specific usecase to understand what it should show etc.

Anyway, you can use R language together with OSM data to get a graph picture:
http://goblor.de/wp/2009/10/17/openstreetmap-projekt-teil2-%E2%80%93-von-den-rohdaten-zum-gerichteten-graphen/

Comment: mmmm.... it will help me (y)